# Why retrofit returns a null amount from webservice?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have an ASP.NET web API service that returns `{"id":1,"family":"mohsen"}`. Why does Retrofit return null from it instead?

API interface:

```
public interface ApiRefrence {
    @GET("hello")
    Call<List<product>> GetProduct();
}
```

API client class:

```
public class ApiClinet {
    public static final String BasesUrl = "http://185.105.239.32/api/test/";
    public static Retrofit ret = null;
    return ret;
}

public  static Retrofit GetApiClinet() {
    if(ret == null) {
        ret = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BasesUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Product class POJO:

```
public class product {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    int id;
    @SerializedName("family")
    @Expose
    String family;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText txt1,txt2;
    List<product> lst;
    TextView txt3;
    private ApiRefrence ref;

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView) ;
        txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        ref = ApiClinet.GetApiClinet().create(ApiRefrence.class);

        Call<List<product>> call = ref.GetProduct();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<product>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<product>> call, Response<List<product>>
    response) {               
                lst = response.body();
                txt3.setText(response.body().get(0).family.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<product>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change base url to this:
`public static final String BasesUrl="http://185.105.239.32/api/test/";`

Change your ApiInterface to this:

```
public interface ApiRefrence {
   @GET("hello")
   Call<product> GetProduct();  
}
```

Change your response code:

```
Call<product> call = ref.GetProduct();

call.enqueue(new Callback<product>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<product> call, Response<product>
response) {               
   lst=response.body();

   txt3.setText(response.body().getFamily());
  }

  @Override
   public void onFailure(Call<product> call, Throwable t) {

   }
 });
```

Comment: not solved  error                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.amin.myapplication/com.example.amin.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://185.105.239.32/api/test